# Azure Devops Pull Request decoration with code quality

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request, sonarqube-scan

I need to post the build pipeline summary results (Code coverage, code smell from sonar and other tasks) into the Pull request page.

I've partially succeeded in pulling code coverage results from build quality check tasks using status policy. But I'm stuck in pulling other code quality metrics coming from Sonar(community edition).

Can anyone guide me on how to progress in this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Add your AzureDevops Version (if on premise), and the Sonar Version, they booth had some major changes the last few versions ...

Answer (score 3):

To show the Sonar quality gate Result in Pull request, I suggest that you can set the **Branch policy -> Status Checks** .

1. Set [Pull request trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers) for Pipeline.
2. Add  `SonarQube/quality gate` status check branch policy on the target branch.

[image]

For more info, you can refer to this doc: [Azure DevOps Integration](https://www.hack23.com/sonar/documentation/analysis/azuredevops-integration/)